# Problema con include_onde() al llamar a mi db

Tags: php, mvc, rutas

Tengo esta linea de codigo `include_once('./config/dbh.inc.php)` para incluir la base de datos a un archivo de subida de datos pero me da este error:

```
Warning: include_once(./config/dbh.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto-final\idehome-master\componentes\upload\model.php on line 40

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening './config/dbh.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto-final\idehome-master\componentes\upload\model.php on line 40
```

Lo he probado de mil maneras y me sigue apareciendo este error. Por aqui os dejo la estructura de mis archivos:

[image: El archivo en el que me da el error es el upload/model.php]

Espero que alguien tenga la solucion. Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Indicas que tienes una linea de código pero en el ejemplo no aparece ninguna linea de código aparte la del error, ¿es esa? Si no, deberías colocar el código que te esta provocando el error para que te podamos ayudar de mejor forma.

Comment: @vcasas ya está corregido, muchas gracias!

Comment: has intendado usar `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` para obtener la ruta algo así `$rootPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/idehome-master/';` y pues hacer el include `include_once($rootPath . 'config/dbh.inc.php);`

Comment: @MiguelOsorio muchas gracias! Parece que ya me funciono, un saludo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si llamaras a `./config/dbh.inc.php` desde tu `index.php` la ruta estaría correcta. Si en cambio lo llamas desde `upload/model.php` la ruta debiera ser modificada a:

```
include_once('../config/dbh.inc.php)
```

Lo más sano siempre es usar una ruta absoluta:

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/../config/dbh.inc.php'); // desde model.php
```

o bien

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/config/dbh.inc.php'); // desde index.php
```

Comment: funciona perfectamente!! muchas gracias!!

Comment: Excelente, un problema similar y con tu respuesta lo he solucionado muchas gracias